# SQL Server 2014 CSV Import not recognising end of row/line

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am trying to bulk insert a csv file into SQL Server 2014. I have managed to work out that it is not recognising the end of line character in the CSV file.

The error I get is:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spTempImport, Line 74 Bulk load
>   data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the
>   specified codepage) for row 1, column 51 (Val_0000).

I have read other posts on here and have tried them all and I cannot get it to work.

The SPROC is as follows:

```
 USE [xxxxxxx]
 GO
 /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spTempImport]    Script Date: 26/07/2016 19:59:56 ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[++++++++]

 AS
 BEGIN

 SET NOCOUNT ON

 CREATE TABLE #tmp (
         --[BatchID] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
         [ID] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
         [Serial] NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
         [Date] VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
         [Val_0030]NVARCHAR(15) NULL,       
         [Val_0000]NVARCHAR(15) NULL
     )

     BULK INSERT #tmp
     FROM 'C:\Temp\test1.csv'
     WITH
     (
         FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)


SELECT * FROM  #tmp
```

I have tried using \r \n \n\r \rn CR\LF LF\CR and the various hex codes. I created the file in excel and saved as a CSV and it didn't work. I copied the data into notepad and it wont recognise the line feed/carriage return.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have removed soem of the columns in the code example, the val columns are the same other than the name and `[Val_0000]NVARCHAR(15) NULL` is the final column.

Answer (score 0):

I set the columns in the SPROC to VARCHAR(MAX) and it worked.